# OpenCSV not seeing column that is present in CSV file

Tags: java, opencsv

I am attempting to use OpenCSV to read a CSV into a POJO. When I attempt to parse the CSV I get the following error:

```
Header is missing required fields [LAST NAME]. The list of headers encountered is [Last Name,First Name,User Name,Email,Roles].
```

I am unsure why this error is occurring since the 'Last Name' column is present in the CSV file.

The CSV is:

```
Last Name,First Name,User Name,Email,Roles
Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5
```

The POJO class is:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class SimpleUser {
    @CsvBindByName(column = "First Name", required = true)
    private String firstName;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Last Name", required = true)
    private String lastName;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Email", required = true)
    private String email;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "User Name", required = true)
    private String userName;

    @CsvBindAndSplitByName(column = "Roles", elementType = Double.class, collectionType = LinkedList.class)
    private List<String> roles;
}
```

The OpenCSV code is:

```java
private List<SimpleUser> getCsvUsersFromCsv(String fileLocation) {
    MappingStrategy<SimpleUser> strategy = new FuzzyMappingStrategyBuilder<SimpleUser>().build();
    strategy.setType(SimpleUser.class);

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation)) {
        return new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
                .build()
                .parse();
    }
}
```

Above I used the FuzzyMappingStrategyBuilder just to see if it would change anything but did not.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using OpenCSV version 5.5 with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was a hidden character within my csv file. After testing with a new file it worked as expected.